# Sort PHP by subheaders

Tags: php, sql, sorting, loops, foreach

I am trying to sort my SQL table by subheaders in that table. The output I am trying to get is this:

```
ItemHeader1
-item1
-item2
-item3
ItemHeader2
-item4
-item5
ect.
```

But what I am getting is:

```
ItemHeader1
-item1
-item1
-item1
ect.
```

Here's my PHP Code:

```
$index_content_enquirers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index_content_enquirers WHERE lang_attribute = '$lang_identify' ORDER BY item_sectionname_english ASC, item_english_title ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$get_index_content_enquirers = mysql_fetch_assoc($index_content_enquirers);
$contentinfo = array();

foreach($get_index_content_enquirers as $row) {
    $contentinfo[$get_index_content_enquirers['item_sectionname_english']][] = $get_index_content_enquirers['item_english_title'];
}

foreach($contentinfo as $contenttitle => $item_titles) {
    echo $contenttitle;
    foreach($item_titles as $item_title) {
        echo "<br />". $item_title;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read about escaping strings in queries. You are quite possibly setting yourself up for SQL injection attacks. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all - don't use the mysql functions as they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO.

In this loop:

```
foreach($get_index_content_enquirers as $row) {
    $contentinfo[$get_index_content_enquirers['item_sectionname_english']][] = 
         $get_index_content_enquirers['item_english_title'];
}
```

You should use `$row` instead of `$get_index_content_enquirers`. This will do the trick :)

```
foreach($get_index_content_enquirers as $row) {
    $contentinfo[$row['item_sectionname_english']][] = 
         $row['item_english_title'];
}
```

Comment: When I use $row it gives me an "Warning: Illegal string offset" error?